# Difference between bash,ksh,tcsh and zsh

Tags: linux, shell, posix

Consider the following shell code:

```
unset foo
echo "${foo-'}'}"
```

The result depends on which shell is used:

- bash: `'}'`
- ksh: `''}`
- tcsh: `Missing }.`
- zsh: `''}`

Which shell(s) behave(s) according to the POSIX standard?

Comment: I think ash and dash are POSIX-compliants.

Comment: What is the expected output of a POSIX shell?

Answer (score 2):

A POSIX-compliant shell should output:

```
''}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why? Or maybe point to a relevant web-resource about POSIX-compliants shells? Or POSIX manual relevant section that describes the shell behavior in the case described in question?

Comment: You have double quotes around the expression. The single quote inside the braces is hence not a delimiting quote. You basically have `${foo-'}`. This means: If foo is not set, replace a single quote. This is the first single quote in the output. After the closing brace, the shell finds a second single quote followed by a closing curly brace. Since this too is still inside the outermost enclosing quote, these two characters are printed too. If you would instead write ` echo ${foo-'}'}`, a single curly brace would be printed.

Comment: [The comment should go in the answer]. In any case, the references: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 (first table), and paragraph (before table which start with "In addition, a parameter expansion can be modified..": `'` has no special meaning here